# Постоянное линейное движение физического спрайта

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d, box2d

Есть уровень созданный из статичных физ. объектов (Box2d), на уровне есть динамический объект (аля главный герой игры), нужно сделать так что бы он автоматически постоянно двигался вперед c одной скоростью.

Например если будет горочка, то он должен подниматься и спускаться с нее с той же скоростью что и по прямой и не подлетать на горочках как на трамплинах, т.е. идти строго по линии. Т.е. он должен быть физ объектом, но что бы на него не действовало ускорение/замедление силы тяжести.

Я не совсем понимаю как это делать с физикой. Пробовал использовать`box2dBody->ApplyLinearImpulse` и `box2dBody->SetLinearVelocity`, но это именно импульс, а нужна постоянная скорость.

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Для постоянного движения героя, нужно в **init()** добавить вот такой код

```
this->scheduleUpdate();
```

Затем добавить метод **update(float dt)**, и в нём изменять позицию героя.

Получить позицию героя:

```
int _x = m_heroes->getPosition().x;
int _y = m_heroes->getPosition().y;
```

И поместить в новую позицию:

```
m_heroes->setPosition(_x, _y);
```

И добавить героя на сцену:

```
this->addChild(m_heroes)
```